# I can't debug a Xamarin.Android application

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, rider

When I try to debug the application in Visual Studio, I also tried Jetbrains Rider, the application compiles successfully but when it is starting the debugging process, it fails. The debug window shows the following error message:

> Start debugging Android application failed

Just that, without an additional error message. I can only run the application in release mode.

**Notes:** I created a new Xamarin.Android project and I started in debug mode and it works. I checked the build properties and are the same as my original project, so I don't think that reinstalling will solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to debug on? An Emulator or a real device? Is your Android SDK up to date?

Comment: I tried in both and both gave me the same error, and my Android SDK is updated.

Comment: What does the output window say during its build and launching of the app, sometimes the output of the build lets us know what is the issue

Comment: I've read the build output window and any kind of error message is not displayed, or something that indicates to me that is wrong.

Comment: And the startup project you have selected is indeed a Android _App_ project and not a library?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I can start the application in release mode but not in debug mode

Comment: Have you tried editing the csproj manually compared the debug and release configurations? Probably something weird snuck in there. It is not very easy to help you with the information you have provided.

Comment: @Dylan Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: @Cinorid i didn't solve this problem, i tried copy and pasting only the source files and it works but it's not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by noticing that AssemblyInfo.cs has invalid values for in placed attributes.

Comment: can you explain witch attributes fixed the problem?